# Create full Exception object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I want a reference to an Exception object that includes all the normal information - message, backtrace, etc.

Exception has a `new` method, but it doesn't populate the backtrace:

```
exception = Exception.new("my message")
exception.backtrace
#=> nil
```

The docs say there is a [set_backtrace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Exception.html#method-i-set_backtrace) method, but you have to supply the backtrace yourself (it doesn't just use the current stack).

I can work around this by raising and rescuing:

```
exception = begin
  raise Exception, "my message"
rescue Exception => e
  e
end
exception.backtrace
#=> ["(irb):4:in 'irb_binding'", ...]
```

but that doesn't feel very clean.

Is there a simple way to create a fully populated Exception object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current stack trace can be obtained from `Kernel#caller`, so you could do

```
exception = Exception.new("my message")
exception.set_backtrace(caller)
```

I guess creating an `Exception` object without raising it immediately basically only makes sense when you are planning to pass it around. Therefore it makes sense that the backtrace must be set manually.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. It would be nice to be have it be a one liner, but I think you are right - it does make more sense this way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is `Kernel#caller_locations`:

```
def a; b; end
def b; c; end

def c
  caller_locations
end

a.each { |trace| p trace }
# => 
# "test.rb:2:in `b'"
# "test.rb:1:in `a'"
# "test.rb:8:in `<main>'"
```

The difference with `Kernel#caller` is caller delivers String objects. `caller_locations` gives `Thread::Backtrace::Location` objects. I don't see any other differences, so `caller_locations` seems a bit more versatile to me -- having methods like `lineno`, `path`, etc which might come in handy.

Comment: Note that `caller_locations` contains objects of type `Thread::Backtrace::Location` whereas `caller` returns just an array of `String`s. Other than that, they contain the same locations.

Comment: @p11y heh, I was just looking at that and updated my answer without noticing your response. But yes, you are right of course :)

Comment: Btw it's not critique, just noticed it :) `caller_locations` actually will come in handy in most cases!

Comment: I know, you were right to point it out, it was good additional information!

Comment: Some good information, but unfortunately `set_backtrace` can't accept an array of `Thread::Backtrace::Location` objects. It has to be an array of strings.

Comment: That is true, although a `map(&:to_s)` would solve that one. But of course if you are *only* interested in the Strings and nothing else, `caller` is the way to go.